# onUpgrade and onCreate doesn't running when i called it

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with SQLite, it doesn't work when i call DataBaseHelper(who store the onCreate and onUpgrade method), even if the version of DataBase change, and i have no errors.

For resuming my application, my main activity call the Singleton, who execute DataBaseHelper.

My main Activity :

```
public class irdesApplication extends Activity {

public static final String LOG_TAG="Droidnova";
private Context context = this;
CheckUpdate chUp;
ProgressBar bar;
TextView txtLoading;
Data d = new Data();
Singleton s;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.page_loading);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBarLoad);
    txtLoading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoading);
    new Thread(myThread).start();
    bar.setProgress(0);

    //Initialisation de la Base
    s.getInstance(context);

    // ---------- Constitution des logs  ------------ //

    int logParam =0;
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "logParam value" + logParam);
    [...]

}
```

}

My Singleton :

```
package com.irdes.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class Singleton {

private static Singleton instance;
private DataBaseHelper baseIrdes;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Data d = new Data();

private Singleton(Context context){
    System.out.println("Construction du Singleton");
    d.loadPercent = 10;
    d.loadTxt = "Initialisation";
    baseIrdes = new DataBaseHelper(context, d.dbName, null, d.dbVersion);
}

public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance == null)
        instance = new Singleton(context);
        return instance;
}

public void setValue(SQLiteDatabase value){
    db = value;
}
public SQLiteDatabase getValue(){
    return db;
}

protected void open(){
    //on ouvre la BDD en écriture
    db = baseIrdes.getWritableDatabase();
}

protected void close(){
    //on ferme l'accès à la BDD
    db.close();
}
```

}

My DataBasHelper Activity :

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private Data d = new Data();

public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    System.out.println("Test");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    d.updateDataBase = true;
    //Activation prise en charge Foreign Keys
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");

    [...]
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+d.actualiteTable+" ("+d.colActualiteNum+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+
            d.colActualiteTitre+ " TEXT, "+d.colActualiteDate+" TEXT, "+d.colActualiteLien+" TEXT, "+d.colActualiteTypeActu+" INTEGER, " +
                    "FOREIGN KEY ("+d.colActualiteTypeActu+") REFERENCES "+d.typeActuTable+" ("+d.colTypeActuNum+"))");
    [...]
      System.out.println("Create table Complete");
      InsertRows(db);
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    [...]
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+d.actualiteTable);
    [...]

    onCreate(db);

}

public void InsertRows (SQLiteDatabase bdd){

    System.out.println("Chargement des données");

    bdd = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    // --------- TypeActu -------- //

    cv.put(d.colTypeActuNum, 1);
    cv.put(d.coltypeActuLibelle, "Gen");
    bdd.insert(d.typeActuTable, d.colTypeActuNum, cv);
    [...]
    bdd.close();
    System.out.println("Données inserées");
```

}

And Data class for more comprehension :

```
public static final String dbName="irdesDB";
public static final int dbVersion=46;

public static final String actualiteTable="Actualite";
public static final String colActualiteNum="numActu";
public static final String colActualiteTitre="titre";
public static final String colActualiteDate="date";
public static final String colActualiteLien="lien";
public static final String colActualiteTypeActu="numTypeActu";
[...]
```

I have aslo posted in a french forum here, if it could help: http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1110144/java/general-java/java-mobiles/android/sqlite-onupgrade-ne-s-execute-plus/#post6141983

What's the problem ? I don't understand why onCreate and onUpgrade doesn't executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods are only called when you call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`.

In your case, invoke the baseIrdes.`open()` method.

The same problem was address [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791852/android-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-method-is-not-called-why/6791968#6791968).

Answer (score 1):

According to the API..

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
```

> Since: API Level 1
>
> Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. This method always returns very quickly. The database is not actually created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() is called.

So you have to make sure you run `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`.  I see you have `getWritableDatabase()` in your `open()` method, but I don't see where you are running your open method?  I have not used a database helper personally, so there could be something I'm unaware of, but I don't see where your `open()` is executed at all..

Comment: Looks like I was too late.  (Loaded the page and spent a bunch of time looking at the code)  *shrug*  Glad the problem was solved.  :)